# Multiple forms, keep original input even though form is never used again

Tags: vb.net

in my project I have 3 forms.

On the first form is a textbox which gathers a username, which is then checked against a database and, if confirmed, logs the user into the project.

On the third form, there is a label that displays the username that was entered in the first forms' textbox. When the user is done with a project, they click a button that gives them the choice if they wish to start over...if yes is clicked, they start over from the second form (I don't want them to have to "login" again.

The first general run through the program works fine (first -> second -> third form)...
My problem is, since the first form was closed, never to be seen again, the data that was entered in the first forms' textbox is now gone and the third forms' label just displays "label1"

Is there a way to make it so they user logs in once (the first form) and then continues on about the project (going through the second and third forms over and over again) without having to login again? And having that label KEEP the original "username"?

Thanks to everyone in advance!

Comment: You need to re-think the way the project hangs together, and specifically the role of forms. You could have a module which acts as the main program, where these variables are kept, and use the forms as simply ways to display and collect data; a presentation layer, if you will.

Comment: Use a module to store the `Username`. You can then reference to that.

Comment: @peterG Thank you for saying that! Just thinking about it made sense and implementing that thought process worked perfectly. Very much appreciated!

Bugs I did try peterG's sugesstion first and since it ended up working I didn't use the "module" approach, however your input is very much appreciated!